# Text to table, create row (not column) at delimiter that is not paragraph mark

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to convert text to table, that has formatting (numbered and bulleted list).
I tried replacing paragraph mark with other characters and it converts the text to table as I want it, but it messes up numbering and bulleted list and formatting (removes it).

I would like to make a table row (one column) that starts at custom delimiter or bookmark and ends when the delimiter reappears like this (delimiter in this case is Ł):

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to remove the borders of all cells **put them inside one cell** then drag and drop the contents to other areas of your document.

Comment: This is not what I want. The text is not in cell, it is plain formatted text in word that I want to put into table, with a custom delimiter, that would keep the formatting. There are hundreds of cell that I would have to do this for manually.